# Setting the machine proxy via dsc

Tags: powershell, proxy, dsc

I would like to setup a machines proxy configuration via DSC, has anyone done this already or know which dsc resource I should be using?

I've tried setting the registry keys following https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/dsc-configuring-a-proxy/

Comment: Have you tried the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a resource or  user a script resource using this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_5

```
NetSH Winhttp
set proxy myproxy
set proxy myproxy:80 "<local>bar"
set proxy proxy-server="http=myproxy;https=sproxy:88" bypass-list="*.contoso.com"
```

This sets the system wide proxy and if I remember correctly will not override user settings.